# Unexpected default constructor call when using move semantics

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have two similar pieces of code. The first version unexpectedly calls the default constructor while the second doesn't. They both call the move operator / move constructor, respectively, as expected.

```
class MyResource
{
public:
    MyResource() : m_data(0) { std::cout << "Default Ctor" << std::endl; }
    MyResource(int data) : m_data(data) { std::cout << "Int Ctor" << std::endl; }

    MyResource(MyResource const& other) = delete;
    MyResource& operator=(MyResource const& other) = delete;

    MyResource(MyResource&& other) noexcept : m_data(other.m_data) { std::cout << "Move Ctor" << std::endl; }
    MyResource& operator=(MyResource&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Op" << std::endl; m_data = other.m_data; return *this; }

    ~MyResource() { std::cout << "Dtor" << std::endl; }

private:
    int m_data = 0;
};

class MyWrapper
{
public:
    MyWrapper(MyResource&& resource)
        // : m_resource(std::move(resource)) // Version 2
    {
        // m_resource = std::move(resource); // Version 1
    }

private:
    MyResource m_resource;
};
```

My test usage is:

```
MyWrapper* wrapper = new MyWrapper(MyResource(1));
delete wrapper;
```

With Version 1, I get:

> Int Ctor
> **Default Ctor**
> Move Op
> Dtor
> Dtor

While Version 2 outputs:

> Int Ctor
> Move Ctor
> Dtor
> Dtor

What's the reason behind this difference?
Why does version 1 call the default constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members are initialized before the construct body runs. A much simpler example to see the same:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo(int) { std::cout << "ctr\n";}
    foo() { std::cout << "default ctr\n";}
    void operator=(const foo&) { std::cout << "assignment\n"; }
};

struct bar {
    foo f;
    bar(int) : f(1) {}
    bar() {
        f = foo();
    }
};

int main() {
    bar b;
    std::cout << "---------\n";
    bar c(1);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/nWrh577o6):

```
default ctr
default ctr
assignment
---------
ctr
```

You cannot initialize a member in the body of the constructor! If you do not provide an initializer, either in the member initializer list or as an in class initializer, then `f` is default constructed. In the constructor body you can only assign to an already initialized member.